# Finding the solid angle of a beach ball

Tags: vision, perception

Suppose I have a beach ball whose radius is 0.5m, and the distance between myself and the center of the beach ball is 10m. How do I go about setting up a diagram for finding the solid angle of the beach ball?

My understanding is that the solid angle of the beach ball is what is subtended by the beach ball itself as viewed from the center of a hypothetical sphere (in this case, my eyes). What I do not understand is where this sphere is in relation to the beach ball. Is the beach ball outside of the sphere and tangent to it? Is the edge of the sphere defined by the center of the beach ball, in this case 10m away?

I have found basically no examples online about a helpful graphical representation of setting up this kind of seemingly simple problem.

On Wikipedia, there is a formula $$\Omega = A/r^2 $$

where A is the area of the intersection of the circular cap that is formed by a cone whose apex is at the center of the sphere, with the sphere itself, whose own radius is $r$. What i'm missing is the relationship of that cone with the object in question. Does the cone contain the beach ball in this case, with the sides of the beach ball tangent to the interior of the cone?

Comment: Yeah, the distance to the object defines the radius of the sphere. So if you imagine yourself enclosed in a spherical room with the beach ball glued to the wall, as such a room shrinks or expands, it's clear that the ball will cover a larger or smaller solid angle. I think the radius of the ball can be neglected in this regard (only use it to calculate the angle)

Comment: Actually if you want to be more accurate you can use the formula for celestial objects here:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle that takes into account also the radius of spherical object itself

Answer (score 3):

Draw lines from your eye to every visible part of the object and then intersect those lines with a perfect sphere of small radius $r$ (in your example maybe $r$ should be 1m or 0.5m centered on your eye. The surface area $s$ subtended on the sphere, divided by $r^2$, is the solid angle.

For a ball, this procedure defines a cone which is **tangent to the ball**.  For very long distances $L$ this is just the equator of the ball and thus asymptotically the solid angle must go like $\pi (R/L)^2$, but this can't be true as the ball gets close. For one thing when $R=L$ we are talking about putting your eye directly against the beach ball, obviously it must take up $2\pi$ steradians, half your viewing field. For another, from that point you cannot see any of the ball except what is in contact with your eye.

Drawing the trigonometric diagram, we have a right triangle with one foot $R$ and hypotenuse $L$, defining an angle $\psi$ where $\sin\psi = R/L.$ Then the surface area on the circle of radius $r$ comes from integrating in spherical coordinates,
$$
\begin{align}
A(\psi)&=\int_0^\psi r~\mathrm d\phi~\int_0^{2\pi}r\sin\phi\mathrm d\theta\\
&=2\pi r^2(1-\cos\psi)\\
&=2\pi r^2\left(1-\sqrt{1-{R^2\over L^2}}\right).
\end{align}$$
For $R\ll L$ this simplifies as predicted above, but for the case where you are near the Earth we would instead say $L=R +\delta x,$ solid angle would be $2\pi (1-(\delta x/R))$.

Comment: "...and then intersect those lines with a perfect sphere of small radius r". 

I'm thinking about that like this: The rays which are tangent to the ball create a ring of points that lie on the ball. If I intersect those points with a sphere whose center is at my eyeball, it is the area of that circular "cap" (which is slightly beyond those points) which defines the solid angle (once divided by $r^2$)?

Comment: That also works, it is a special case where we eschew the idea of "small $r$" (which means that the sphere might not *intersect* the line segment but might also *lie beyond*  it) and we are very careful to note that the radius of this sphere is, by trig, actually $r = \sqrt{L^2 - R^2}.$ But other than those two considerations yes that is a valid choice.

Comment: Also worth pointing out, this idea of directly intersecting with a sphere only works for certain geometries, the general $r$ case is simpler. For instance if you wanted to know the solid angle taken up by °two* balls, $R_1, R_2, L_1, L_2$ that might occlude each other, well, you can't put the sphere of radius $r$ on one ball without the sphere being off the other, so you'd want to try to project them into spherical coordinates and then get each one's radius on that sphere and also the distance between them, and see how much occluded area is double-counted by just adding the two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The sphere is centered on your eye's pupil.

> the distance between myself and the center of the beach ball is 10m

This is your clue -- the center of the beach ball is located on the surface of a sphere, 10m away from you.

> What i'm missing is the relationship of that cone with the object in question

If you take a cone as being a 3D solid, then the cone is comprised of all of the points that are on lines that radiate from the cone's center and intersect with the beach ball.

If you take the cone as being a 2D shell in 3D space, then the cone is comprised of those lines that radiate from the center and are tangent to the surface of the beach ball.

Perhaps this diagram will help you understand the geometry.  Then, if you don't want to depend on someone else's formulas, you can work out the math yourself:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line to the center of the ball, d ,the radius r  to the tangent line and the tangent are a rectangular   triangle, the half angle to your ey than is $\tan(\alpha/2)=r/d$